# Reading pdf file using tabula in python

Tags: python, tabula

I am trying to read pdf file using tabula in python but receiving these error, here is the code.I am using python version 3.7 and tabula version 2.0.1

```
from tabula import read_pdf
df=read_pdf('txt.pdf',pages='all')
print(df)
```

these are the errors I am receiving

```
    Python37_64\lib\site-packages\tabula\io.py", line 85, in _run
    check=True, 

    Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 488, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:

    Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this

```
from tabula import read_pdf
df=read_pdf('txt.pdf',pages='all')
df
```

or

```
from tabula import read_pdf
df=read_pdf('txt.pdf',pages='all')
df[0]
```

and you shall be good to go